# Problema com precisão de variável tipo double

Tags: c, c++, valor-monetário

Estou resolvendo a questão 1021 do URI judge, mas estou com um problema quanto a precisão do meu valor de entrada. Segue o código base:

```
#include <iostream.h>
int main(){
double a;
cin >> a;
}
```

O problema é que, caso eu insira por exemplo 0.35 na entrada, por algum motivo a variável a recebe 0.349999, porém eu preciso desse 0.001 perdido para resolver a questão, o que eu posso fazer para corrigir isso?

Comment: Se você necessita de precisão então não utilize variáveis do tipo float ou double pois estes tipos de dados são inerentemente imprecisos. Se efetivamente precisar trabalhar com estes tipos de dados então considerar um erro vai resolver o problema, por ex. + ou um erro de 1E-5 (ou 0.00001). Para este problema em particular você pode utilizar um tipo de dado inteiro e multiplique os valores por 100 para determinar as quantidades de notas e moedas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está em [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101). Como você não vai usar um tipo mais adequado em um exercício a solução é equalizar tudo para inteiro, então o ideal é a pessoa digitar a quantidade de centavos como um inteiro, mas se o exercício exigir a entrada como `double` a primeira coisa que deve fazer é equalizar multiplicando por 100, aí tudo é tratado com inteiro, fica até mais fácil resolver a questão. Pegar o dado como `double` e multiplicar não garante que sempre ficará certo, mas já evita muitos erros, pelo menos para passar no teste. Portanto o exercício é ruim em incentiva práticas inadequadas, por isso que eu falo que confiar em coisas na internet sempre é um perigo.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, realmente multiplicar por 100 deixa tudo mais tranquilo.

Comment: @RicardoCoutinho Veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.